# How do I only show results of documents created within 24 hours

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm creating a story feature and would only like to show posts that have been made within 24 hours.

I presume I use the timestamp and todays date to filter the results, but I'm unsure how I would do it.

My code is below:

```
    func fetchStories(completion: @escaping([Story]) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("stories")
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
        .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            let stories = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Story.self) })
            completion(stories)
        }
}
```

Story object:

struct Story: Identifiable, Decodable {
@DocumentID var id: String?
let timestamp: Timestamp
let photoUrl: String
let uid: String
var likes: Int

```
var user: User?
var didLike: Bool? = false

var timestampString: String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth]
    formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
    formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    return formatter.string(from: timestamp.dateValue(), to: Date()) ?? ""
}
```

}

Comment: what have you tried so far? What did not work? Array have a `filter` function, here is some more info on this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/filter(_:)

Comment: can you show the code for `Story`.